# How do I get my NPC to point towards a waypoint?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a novice in every sense of the word, and cannot figure out how to do it. I know it is something with vectors though. Here is my current code. Problem is that the npc turns and faces the direction that the waypoint is facing, instead of pointing in it's relative direction.

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject[] waypoints;
    public GameObject player;
    int current = 0;
    public float speed;
    public float rotSpeed;
    float WPradius = 1;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Vector3.Distance(waypoints[current].transform.position, transform.position) < WPradius)
        {
            current = Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
            if (current >= waypoints.Length)
            {
                current = 0;
            }
        }
        
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypoints[current].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, waypoints[current].transform.rotation, Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed);
        
    }

   
} ```
````

Comment: could you please provide more information in your question about the context? What do you want to achieve with the Waypoints object? What does the NPC mean in your question?

Comment: You could “look at” the way point at eyelevel (should there be eyes but t the same y height as you are now)

Answer (score 0):

Using `waypoints[current].transform.rotation` in `RotateTowards` will get the rotation OF the object. You are interested in the rotation which makes local forward point in the direction from `transform.position` to `waypoints[current].transform.position` and also aligns local up as close to global up as possible. You can use [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) to determine that rotation:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Vector3.Distance(waypoints[current].transform.position, transform.position) 
            < WPradius)
    {
        current = Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length);
        if (current >= waypoints.Length)
        {
            current = 0;
        }
    }
    
    Vector3 waypointPos = waypoints[current].transform.position;
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, waypointPos,
            Time.deltaTime * speed);

    Quaternion goalRot = Quaternion.LookRotation(waypointPos - transform.position);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, goalRot, 
            Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed);
    
}
```